# setOnclickListener event is not working for Floating action button in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button

Here is the xml code for this.....this is in constraint layout with a recycler view

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:contentDescription="@string/add_book" />
```

and the Activity Code for this is here

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val fab = binding.fabAdd

    fab.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this,AddActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be done like this.

You have to `setContentView` as `root` of `view binding` not `layout`.

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

@Override
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.fab_add.setOnClickListener {
       val intent = Intent(this,AddActivity::class.java)
       startActivity(intent)
    }  
}
```

Comment: i tried this but now the app keeps stopping

Comment: @AnkitVerma Please post *error log* inside question so that i can get idea may be something other is been wrong.

Comment: solved i got the error... my result avtivity i.e AddActivity had the binding defind above the oncreate function and that was the error...thanks for the support

Comment: @AnkitVerma Glad it helped ! Pls accept the answer by clicking check mark correct so that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)


    val fab = binding.fabAdd

    fab.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this,AddActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```